(Zero Inflated) Negative Binomial Regression with Conley Standard Errors and Weights
My goal is to run a negative binomial regression with conley standard errors and weights. Further below I separately ask about a zero-inflated negative binomial model.
To my knowledge, a negative binomial regression can be run with glm.nb() and fenegbin().
In the first, I can use weights, in the second I can implement conley standard errors. Vice versa I am currently not able to apply the repective options.
(Maybe of relevance: the weights are entropy balancing weights in the actual application.)
Reprex:
library(MASS)
library(modelsummary)
library(fixest)

# Step 2: Create a dummy dataframe
set.seed(123)  # For reproducibility
n <- 100  # Number of observations

# Dummy data
data <- data.frame(
  y = rnbinom(n, size = 1, mu = 10),  # Negative binomial response variable
  x1 = rnorm(n),  # Continuous predictor
  x2 = rbinom(n, 1, 0.5),  # Binary predictor
  weight = runif(n, 0.5, 2),  # Weights
  lat = runif(n, -90, 90),  # Latitude
  lon = runif(n, -180, 180)  # Longitude
)



Either I have:
m1 <- glm.nb(y ~ x1 + x2, data = data, weights = weight)

...where I could not find out how to apply conley standard errors.
Or, I have:
m2 <- fenegbin(y ~ x1 + x2, data=data,
                vcov=vcov_conley(cutoff=100, lat="lat",lon="lon"))

...where weights seem to be unavailable.
I also tried
m3a <- fenegbin(y ~ x1 + x2, data=data,
             vcov=vcov_conley(cutoff=100, lat="lat",lon="lon"),
             only.env=TRUE)
m3 <- est_env(m3a, weights = data$weight)

...which runs through but does not alter the results. Something is amiss.
I report (and later export) the results in modelsummary.
modelsummary(list(m1,m2,m3),stars=T)

...where I am aware that the 'vcov' option is quite versatile. I could not, however, find an option for conley standard errors.

I also need this for a zero-inflated negative binomial (zinb) model.
The model looks like this, lacking the conley standard errors:
library(pscl)
m4 <- zeroinfl(y ~ x1 + x2 , data=data, dist="negbin", weights=weight)

Any help is much appreciated!

To the best of my knowledge, I don't think it is possible to achieve what you want, with base R or any packages that I am aware of. Of course, that doesn't mean I haven't overlooked something.
As you have discovered:

MASS::glm.nb() supports weights, but does not support Conley standard errors.
fixest::fenegbin() supports Conley standard errors, but does not support weights.
pscl::zeroinfl() supports weights but does not support Conley standard errors.

...none of which is satisfactory for your requirements. Among the possibilities is to use standard errors that mimic the properties of Conley SEs, for example using the clubSandwichpackage. Another possibility is to implement your own computation for Conley SEs. I fiddled around trying to do this, but I didn't get very far and I don't have the time to go much further with it at the moment. Here is what I have. Perhaps you or others can take it a bit further. The general approach is:

Compute the pairwise distances between observations based on their spatial coordinates to obtain a distance matrix
Use a cutoff distance to determine which pairs of observations should influence each other.
Adjust the empirical estimation function using the spatial weights.

I hesitate to post this code, since it doesn't work as intended, but I will go ahead anyway and hope that someone finds it useful:
The data should look like this:
> head(data)
   y         x1 x2    weight        lat         lon
1  3  0.8793641  0 1.4801417   8.645812   -7.786999
2 22  0.9231292  0 1.8739795 -64.683686  101.508809
3 10  0.6931340  1 1.7196697 -59.441571 -163.430443
4  2 -0.1395003  0 1.5138350  47.157358  115.144080
5 10 -3.3106787  0 1.7112487   4.931089  -83.012959
6 18  0.5384658  0 0.6920966  64.978084  -78.173851

# Function to compute Conley standard errors
conley_se <- function(model, lat, lon, cutoff, data) {
    #   model  : A fitted model object (glm or glm.nb object)
    #   lat    : The name of the latitude variable 
    #   lon    : The name of the longitude variable 
    #   cutoff : The distance cutoff for determining spatial correlation
    #   data   : A data frame containing the model variables and coordinates 

  coordinates <- cbind(data[[lat]], data[[lon]])
  
  # Calculate pairwise distances between observations
  dist_matrix <- sp::spDists(coordinates, longlat = TRUE)
  
  # Apply cutoff distance to create weight matrix
  weight_matrix <- (dist_matrix <= cutoff) * 1
  
  # Compute the empirical estimation function (scores)
  estfun <- sandwich::estfun(model)
  
  # Compute the 'meat' of the sandwich estimator
  meat <- crossprod(estfun) / nrow(estfun)
  
  # Compute the 'bread' of the sandwich estimator
  bread <- sandwich::bread(model)
  
  # Initialize the HAC covariance matrix
  vcov_hac <- bread %*% meat %*% bread
  
  # Adjust the covariance matrix for spatial correlation
  # This loop incorporates the spatial weights based on distances
  for (i in 1:nrow(weight_matrix)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(weight_matrix)) {
      if (i != j && weight_matrix[i, j] != 0) {
        vcov_hac <- vcov_hac + weight_matrix[i, j] * outer(estfun[i, ], estfun[j, ])
      }
    }
  }
  
  # Return the adjusted covariance matrix
  return(vcov_hac)
}

Usage:
# Fit negative binomial model with weights
m1 <- glm.nb(y ~ x1 + x2, data = data, weights = weight)

# Compute Conley standard errors
conley_vcov <- conley_se(m1, "lat", "lon", 100, data)

# Summary with custom Conley standard errors
summary1 <- coeftest(m1, vcov = conley_vcov)


also glmmTMB. Not obvious to me how to deal with the zero-inflation component when computing robust SEs?

At least for ols and poisson I could cross-check with the conleyreg  commands. After adding vcov_hac <- vcov_hac/100 before the return command, the results are the same. This only works for the cutoff=100, however. I'll keep looking...
Also: Alternatively to your sp::spDists, one could use
dist_matrix <- conleyreg::dist_mat(data,lat=lat,lon=lon)  dist_matrix <- dist_matrix[["distances"]]
The differences are minimal, but it helped to compare to the conleyreg regression results.

The differences in distances are considerable but the standard errors are similar between the two distance matrix commands.
In the dummy dataset there is no distance <=100. Check via:
`dist_matrix <- conleyreg::dist_mat(data,lat="lat",lon="lon")
dist_matrix <- dist_matrix[["distances"]]
upper_triangle <- dist_matrix[upper.tri(dist_matrix)]
summary(upper_triangle)
sum(upper_triangle<=1000)/length(upper_triangle)`
